# how to var_dump cart session in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce

```
// method for new woocommerce
echo 'Cart Dump: ' . var_dump( WC()->session->cart);
//it show as 'null'

/// method for old woocommerce
global $woocommerce;
var_dump($_SESSION);
var_dump($woocommerce->cart->get_cart());
```

I use both of them but neither var_dump cart session work. how to var_dump cart session in woocommerce?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where are you trying to put your dump?  If you put this exact code in your functions.php file, you should get the full contents as a WC_Cart object:

```
add_action('init', 'dump_woocommerce_cart');
function dump_woocommerce_cart() {
    global $woocommerce;
    var_dump($woocommerce->cart);
}
```

Let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: object(WC_Cart)[244]
  public 'cart_contents' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'removed_cart_contents' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'applied_coupons' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'coupon_discount_amounts' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'coupon_discount_tax_amounts' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'coupon_applied_count' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'coupons' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'cart_contents_total' => null

Comment: it's show as null item in the cart, so I couldn't see what is in the cart, I think it because action start at 'init'

Answer (score 5):

To show the actual content in the cart by var_dump cart session

```
//var dump cart session
add_action('the_content', 'dump_woocommerce_cart');
function dump_woocommerce_cart() {
    global $woocommerce;
    var_dump($woocommerce->cart);
}
```

Thanks to the answer from Jonathan!

Answer (score 0):

you can add to any file in your theme lets say header.php

```
global $woocommerce;
var_dump($woocommerce->cart);
```