# Retrieving a var_dump of WooCommerce cart items' permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions, woocommerce-product-bundles

I am trying to access the cart data of a WooCommerce cart containing bundled subscription products. I am using both the WooCommerce Product Bundles and Subscriptions plug ins.

Ultimately I need the cart items' permalinks including the URL parameters but at this stage I can't even make WC `var_dump()` the cart contents.

There is probably an obvious error in my PHP - what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
    function playboi_carti() {
    
        /* none of these three things works, trying each independently */
        
        /*
        if (WC()->cart->get_cart() != NULL) {
            var_dump(WC()->cart->get_cart());
        } else {
            echo('No cart item!');
        }
        */
        
        /*
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            var_dump($cart_item);
        }
        */
        
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
            $product_permalink = $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item );
            var_dump($product_permalink);
        }
        
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'playboi_carti' );
```

The stack trace throws essentially the same error whenever I try the above in any combination:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_cart() on null in wp-content/themes/canine-catering-theme/functions.php:71
Stack trace:
#0 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): playboi_carti()
#1 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#2 wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action()
#3 wp-settings.php(598): do_action()
#4 wp-config.php(105): require_once('wp-...')
#5 wp-load.php(50): require_once('wp-...')
#6 wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('wp-...')
#7 wp-admin/theme-editor.php(10): require_once('wp-...')
#8 {main}
thrown
```

When I try the following (from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657057/how-to-var-dump-cart-session-in-woocommerce)):

```
    add_action('init', 'dump_woocommerce_cart');
    function dump_woocommerce_cart() {
        global $woocommerce;
        var_dump($woocommerce->cart);
    }
```

I do get a var_dump of an empty cart even though there are (bundled subscription) products in the cart. *Also apparently it's bad to use the $woocommerce global??*

Is this lack of cart to do with the Product Bundles or Subscriptions plug ins?

Comment: your error is saying that you're trying to call i.e. `<NULL>.get_cart()` so `WC->cart` must be NULL

Comment: @EricReed Could this part of the "empty cart" var_dump have to do with it?

  object(WC_Cart_Session)#16919 (1) {
    ["cart":protected]=>
    *RECURSION*
  }
  ["fees_api":protected]=>
  object(WC_Cart_Fees)#16922 (3) {
    ["fees":"WC_Cart_Fees":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["cart":"WC_Cart_Fees":private]=>
    *RECURSION*

Comment: formatting's messed up -- please edit post with code and result. thanks :)

Comment: Change 'init' to some other hook that's running on the cart page